# wordpress deleting <object> tag on published

Tags: php, wordpress, object, filter

I have posts that contain flash videos using  tags. I can still see the video or its code when it's **scheduled** but when the posts get published, the  tags are removed resulting to losing the videos I have. I tried to manually edit the time to publish it ahead of time & not wait for 30 mins & the videos are there (not removed at all though published). So videos are removed only when I wait for the posts to get published by wordpress itself. Can somebody enlighten me on what could have caused this? Or probably tell me which file & function I need to check out for when the post goes from scheduled to publish?

How do I skip filtering when posts are transitioned from scheduled/future to published??

Comment: You may have some plugin which use `publish_future_post` hook and filters the videos. Can you post the list of plugins that you have active?

Comment: all in one seo pack,
google analytics,
google sitemap plugin,
gravity forms,
iframe, and
page links to